# Second HTML Button $.post not working

Tags: jquery, html, .post

I have two buttons on my page that will display based on the window width. Both buttons retrieve and use the same values when submitting my page:

```
            var postpage = "/process.cfm";
            var nextpage = "/Thank-You-RN-BSN";
            var values = form.serialize();  

            $.post(postpage, values, function(data){    
                if (data.status == 1){  
                    window.location = nextpage;
                }
            },"json");
```

The first button will run through this code 100% of the time, the second button will get as far as the $.post and then fail. I have no idea why. The values are being populated without issue.

Comment: where's the code for the buttons?

Comment: @jonmrich      Ironically when I went to get the code to paste it in my main post, I realized that I mis-named one of the buttons. :p Your a hero jonmrich.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized after the fact that it came down to simply having a mis-named button. Always check your IDs and Names folks!

Answer (score 1):

use $.ajax() instead to post data.
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: Unless I'm misreading the link you posted, what I'm doing is the exact same thing, only shorthand.

Comment: @Blankdud Yes, your method is shorthand for an ajax POST request. However, the benefit of using $.ajax v. $.post is that there are a lot more configuration options you can do with $.ajax and also error and success handling. Definitely worth a look: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/